# Can we stop buttons and widgets from interfering with one another?

Tags: tkinter, python-3.6

in tkinter i find myself placing widgets and they interfer with one another even though they are on different rows, for example :

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
root = Tk()
multi = Button(root , text ='multiplication')
multi.grid(row = 0 , column = 1 , sticky = W)


addition = Button(root , text = 'addition')
addition.grid(row = 0 , column = 0 , sticky = W)

question = Label(root ,text = 'What is 500 + 500?', font = 'times 10 bold')
question.grid(row = 1, column = 0 , sticky =W)
root.mainloop()
```

is there a way around this , can i make it where they do not interfere with one another , even though they are on seperate rows?my label completely messes up my button in the row above

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have two widgets in column then `tkinter` resizes column to bigger widget.

You can use `sticky="we"` to resize button to the size of column.

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk

root = Tk()

multi = Button(root, text='multiplication')
multi.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky="we") # <---

addition = Button(root, text='addition')
addition.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="we")

question = Label(root, text='What is 500 + 500?', font='times 10 bold')
question.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky="we")

root.mainloop()
```

Or use can use `columnspan=2` for `Label` to put it in two columns

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk

root = Tk()

multi = Button(root, text='multiplication')
multi.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky="w")

addition = Button(root, text='addition')
addition.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="w")

question = Label(root, text='What is 500 + 500?', font='times 10 bold')
question.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky="w", columnspan=2) # <---

root.mainloop()
```

See on effbot.org: [The Tkinter Grid Geometry Manager](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/grid.htm)